# "Xlib: extension "Generic Event Extension" missing on display" warnings

Tags: ubuntu, xorg

How to fix `Xlib` warning: `Xlib:  extension "Generic Event Extension" missing on display`?
A [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=Xlib%3A+%20extension+%22Generic+Event+Extension%22+missing+on+display) returns many results but I still can't fix it :(.
I Tried `sudo apt-get install libxcb-event0` but it didn't help.

I am using Ubuntu on coLinux on Windows XP.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the libraries support an extension that isn't supported by the X server yet. This message is harmless and can be ignored.

Comment: +1. but is it possible to disable this warning ? it fill my terminal where I start X application.